# Can I insert system usernames into SQL chunk in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, knitr, dbplyr

I am trying to use a created variable in knitr SQL chunk. I am attempting to create the variable using `Sys.getenv("USERNAME")` because that is used as part of the schema name. My current code looks like this:

````
```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)

con <-
DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
  .connection_string = 'driver={SQL Server};
  server=server;
  database=db1;
  trusted_connection=true')

BEGINMONTH <- "01JUN16"
ENDMONTH <- "01JUL16"
```

```{SQL, connection=con}
DROP TABLE [SANDBOX_DB].[ORG\USERNAME].TEMP

SELECT VAR1, VAR2, VAR3
  INTO [SANDBOX_DB].[ORG\USERNAME].TEMP
  FROM [DB1].TABLE
  WHERE DATE BETWEEN ?BEGINMONTH AND ?ENDMONTH
```
````

I would like to have an additional variable in the first chunk like this:

```
schema <- paste0("[SANDBOX_DB].[ORG\\", Sys.getenv("USERNAME"), "]")
```

So the final code would look like this:

````
```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)

con <-
DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
  .connection_string = 'driver={SQL Server};
  server=server;
  database=db1;
  trusted_connection=true')

BEGINMONTH <- "01JUN16"
ENDMONTH <- "01JUL16"
schema <- paste0("[SANDBOX_DB].[ORG\\", Sys.getenv("USERNAME"), "]")
```

```{SQL, connection=con}
DROP TABLE ?schema.TEMP

SELECT VAR1, VAR2, VAR3
  INTO ?schema.TEMP
  FROM [DB1].TABLE
  WHERE DATE BETWEEN ?BEGINMONTH AND ?ENDMONTH
```
````

I am getting this error which seems to have to do with the way the parameter is input into the SQL chunk with quotes. Is there another way to implement changing usernames into the SQL chunk?

```
Error: <SQL> 'DROP TABLE '[SANDBOX_DB].[ORG\USERNAME]'.TEMP 

SELECT DISTINCT VAR1, VAR2, VAR3
    INTO '[SANDBOX_DB].[ORG\USERNAME]'.TEMP
    FROM [DB1].TABLE
    WHERE DATE BETWEEN '01JUN16' AND '01JUL16'
'
  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL 
Server]Incorrect syntax near '[SANDBOX_DB].[ORG\USERNAME]'. 
Failed to execute SQL chunk
```

Comment: I don't know SQL Server SQL dialects but if the issue is that `.TEMP` is outside the single quotes, perhaps just put it in the `paste0()` call? I know that I can use a similar construct in other dbs.

Comment: if that doesn't work, let me know as it wouldn't be too hard to write an `mssql` chunk type to work around this issue.

Comment: I have tried this and still ran into the same error. What exactly do you mean by writing an `mssql` chunk type?

Comment: This is the "magic" behind SQL chunks: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/7386aa3960e8126f8accaa35341b578b7af44277/R/engine.R#L462-L584 ; A workaround for you is to make a new `eng_mssql()` engine & chunk type 'mssql' that handles the unique (& shoddy) MS SQL Server syntax SQL foibles like the one you're experiencing. It's not difficult to extend `knitr` engines at all. vis-a-vis https://github.com/hrbrmstr/knitrengines

Comment: I will look into this. Thank you

Comment: Just an idea: if you add `schema <- sql(schema)` at the end of your R chunk, do you obtain a better result?